# Leaflet : how to add color to markers when using a geoJson layer?

Tags: leaflet

I've searched everywhere, or almost, on the web to find a solution to add color to markers to a leaflet map when using geoJson, but in vein. So here I am today asking you how to achieve this little miracle ?

`[Here]`[1](https://codepen.io/petitboeuf/pen/mdrBbJJ) is my map. As you can see, all the markers have the default color, blue. I would like 3 more colors.

I've managed to make the leaflet markercluster plugin work. I was wondering how to make [color-markers](https://github.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers) work.

Thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the icon for each marker:

You have to know a way how to differ the markers, so that you know which marker needs which icon. I used for this the value in the `feature.properties.icon`, this is a custom value

```
L.geoJSON(someGeojsonFeature, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        var _icon = L.icon({
            iconSize: [25, 41],
            iconAnchor: [12, 41],
            popupAnchor: [1, -34],
            shadowSize: [41, 41]
        });

        if (feature.properties.icon == "black") {
            _icon.options.iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-black.png'
        } else if (feature.properties.icon == "gold") {
            _icon.options.iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-gold.png'
        } else if (feature.properties.icon == "green") {
            _icon.options.iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-green.png'
        }

        return L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: _icon
        });
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that before, but I'm still struggling with the location of the pointToLayer block. Does it fit before a OnEachFeature block ?

Comment: it doesn't matter, it has no fixed order because it is a object. Does it work for you? If yes please check my answer. But in generel the executing is first `pointToLayer` and then `onEachFeature`